# get first item in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, twig

I am looping through an array and would like to add a class if it is the first item.

I have tried

```
{% if field|first %}
{% if field.first %}
{% if field.first() %}
{% if loop|first %}
{% if loop.first %}
{% if loop.first() %}
```

none work, please help. *(the reason I don't use css pseudo first is that this is a grid layout and I have am doing responsive layout things with it)*

```
   {% for field in row.fields %}    
       <div class="c-product-table__item {% if field|first %}{{ first_item }}{% endif %}    ">  
          <span class="c-product-table__text">{{ field.text }}</span>   
       </div>
   {% endfor %}
```

I don't know why twig filters are not working, I solved it another way. I set a var and made it blank after first loop

```
  {% set thiscount = 'first_item' %}
  {% for field in row.fields %} 
    <div class="c-product-table__item {{ thiscount }}"> 
      <span class="c-product-table__text">{{ field.text }}</span>   
     </div>
  {% set thiscount = '' %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hello, yes I did, I forgot to post. I updated my description

Comment: seems to be `if loop.first`

Comment: Hello Splash, I tried that

Comment: Hello! `loop.first` is working for me too. You can use `loop.index == 1` too. What version of twig are you using?

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://twigfiddle.com/lw4aom). Also you should not use the filter `first` for this. The filter `first` returns the first element of an arrray, which means any non-false value would make the condition `{% if array|first %}` evaluate to `true`

Comment: https://twigfiddle.com/e2rzvp